# Expanding UITableViewCell won't expand on index rows > 12

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

Heads up, I'm just learning the ropes of iOS development. I have a TableView that uses a custom Cell that toggles its height to give the affect of a "drawer" that drops down when you select it. I almost have it completely working, but I have a really weird problem. Any cells selected with an index row greater than 12 don't change height. **Here's a video to demonstrate.** - http://d.chend.me/4NMU

I'm initializing my custom cell in a pretty standard way, I think.

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"DrawerCell";

NSDictionary *clip = self.isFiltered ? [self.filteredClips objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] : [self.clips objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

DrawerCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:CellIdentifier owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```

My heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method looks like so:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if(self.selectedIndex == [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row])
    {
        return 126.0f;
    }
    else {
        return 60.0f;
    }
}
```

And then for didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];

    if(self.selectedIndex == [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row])
    {
        self.selectedIndex = nil;
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        NSLog(@"Selected Index: %@\nIndex Path Row: %i\n\n", self.selectedIndex, indexPath.row);
        return;
    }

    //First we check if a cell is already expanded.
    //If it is we want to minimize make sure it is reloaded to minimize it back
    if(self.selectedIndex != nil)
    {
        self.selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
        [tableView beginUpdates];
        [tableView endUpdates];
        NSLog(@"Selected Index: %@\nIndex Path Row: %i\n\n", self.selectedIndex, indexPath.row);        
        return;
    }


    //Finally set the selected index to the new selection and reload it to expand
    self.selectedIndex = [NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row];
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView endUpdates];
    NSLog(@"Selected Index: %@\nIndex Path Row: %i\n\n", self.selectedIndex, indexPath.row);    

}
```

Is there any blatant reason why index rows greater than 12 don't work while everything before them works perfectly? Just as a side note, they're still receiving touch events, and logging the proper index path row, they just won't show the drawer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue could (*could*) be your comparison of NSNumbers via `==`. As objects, this compares addresses, not values. Try using `-isEqual:` instead.

Comment: Yep! That was it. A small detail, but made all the difference. Thanks!